# How can I solve this sequence with Riemann integration?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, convergence-divergence, lebesgue-integral, riemann-integration

I have this sequence defined by an improper integral
$\displaystyle \lim_{n \to\infty} \int_0^\infty \cfrac{1}{1+x^2} \log\left(\frac{2nx+3}{nx+1}\right)\ dx$

it is easy to prove that this sequence converges with Lebesgue's integrations, but how can I prove the pointwise convergence with Riemann?

Comment: You don't have any series there: you have the limit of a sequence defined by an improper integral. Is this what you meant to ask?

Comment: I mean yes. Sorry but it's all new stuff for me

Comment: Then edit your question and write it properly.

Comment: FYR, by the dominated convergence theorem, the integral equals $\frac{\pi \log(2)}{2}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use *equivalence*:
$$\log\frac{2nx+3}{nx+1}\sim_{x\to\infty}\log\frac{2nx}{nx}=\log 2, \quad \text{hence }\;\frac1{1+x^2}\log\frac{2nx+3}{n+1}\sim_{x\to\infty} \frac{\log 2}{1+x^2},$$
which converges.

Comment: Thx for your answer. Can you explain why you manipulated only the log part?

Comment: I could have manipulated the ratiobal function part, but it was unnecessary, since it is the derivative of $\arctan$.

Comment: At the beginning, did you mean $\log\frac{2nx+3}{nx+1}$ rather than $\log\frac{2nx+3}{n+1}$? Also, would it not be better to take this equivalence as $n\to\infty$ because $x$ goes to both $0$ and $\infty$? Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I did mean $\log\frac{2nx+3}{nx+1}$, sorry for the typo. For the other question, no, I have to take an equivalent as $x\to\infty$, since it is an improper integral when $x\to\infty$ (on the $0$ side, one should take another equivalent).

Answer (score 1):

$$\log\frac{2nx+3}{nx+1} = \log\frac{2nx+2+1}{nx+1} = \log(2) + log(1+\frac{1}{2nx+2})$$

You can the use dominated convergence theorem since:

For all $x \in \mathbb{R}, $n in N:

$$\log(1+\frac{1}{2nx+2}) \le \frac{1}{2nx+2} \le \frac{1}{2}$$